# Unable to compile class for JSP error when I'm running my code in eclipse gwt project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, gwt, gxt

Hi I'm getting following error when I'm trying to access jsp page in my gwt project. Other pages which are not jsp pages are acessing fine.

***It is strange that I'm able to see JSP file when GWT SDK is moved to bottom in build path order which is giving another error that  GWT SDK is not installed***

Can any one help me please ?

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
Generated servlet error:
2016/01/07 14:30:51:128 IST [ERROR] Compiler - Javac exception  <Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.>Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:933)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:757)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:379)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:472)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:439)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:511)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:295)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
at com.rapapp.gwt.server.common.util.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at com.rapapp.gwt.server.common.util.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)



Generated servlet error:
2016/01/07 14:30:51:129 IST [ERROR] Compiler - Env: Compile:  javaFileName=/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-127.0.0.1-8888-war-_-any-//org/apache/jsp\login_jsp.java
```

Comment: please post your login.jsp

Comment: and please check compiler log -> share that maybe?

Comment: Hi @StefanBeike,I tried but not able posted my code here. But I changed my file that are contained only html basic tags. i.e div and input tags only. Still I got same error. Can you guess what may be the issue ?

Comment: It is strange that I'm able to see JSP file when GWT SDK is moved to bottom in build path order which is giving another error that GWT SDK is not installed

Comment: create a basic jsp file that throws the same error and post that one... without any code there is not much to help

Answer (score 3):

As you are not providing `login.jsp` file, So I want to share couple of suggestions to solve this issue.

1. Use latest tomcat -
   http://www.howopensource.com/2015/07/unable-to-compile-class-for-jsp-the-type-java-util-mapentry-cannot-be-resolved/
2. The `jsp-api` is provided by your `Servlet container`. Use at least `2.1`
   version. Change the dependency in your `pom.xml`

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>     <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
>     <version>2.1</version>
>     <scope>provided</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```

3. Use your bean where `class name` will be written with `package name`. As an example,

> ```
> <%@ page import="com.Test.Person" %> 
> <html> 
> <head></head> 
> <body> 
> <jsp:useBean id="person" class="com.Test.Person" scope="request" /> 
> <jsp:setProperty name="person" property="name" value="Tripti" /> 
> This JSP Page is created by:<jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name" /> 
>
> </body> 
> </html>
> ```

4. The Tomcat container caches `.java` and `.class` files generated by the
   JSP parser they are used by the web application. Sometimes these get
   corrupted or cannot be found. **This may occur after a patch or
   upgrade that contains modifications to JSPs**.

> Resolution

- Delete the contents of the `<JIRA_INSTALL>/work` folder if using
  `standalone JIRA` or `<CATALINA_BASE>/work` if using `EAR/WAR`
  installation.
- Verify the user running the JIRA application process has Read/Write
  permission to the`<JIRA_INSTALL|CATALINA_BASE>/work` directory.
- Restart the JIRA application container to rebuild the files.

**There are also some other ways--**

5. Classes not within a package are discouraged in modern Java, to the
   point where they don't work in a number of cases. Put your classes
   into packages (use a package statement at the top of the .java
   file)--all of them.
6. This problem is generated by the default values used by JspServlet, which compiles using 1.4 for source/target values.

You can configure this servlet by adding

> ```
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
>         <param-value>1.5</param-value>
>     </init-param>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
>         <param-value>1.5</param-value>
>     </init-param>
>     <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
> </servlet>
> ```

7. There is one more issue as you can't configure JspServlet with the current `jasper-compiler-5.0.28`. You should download `jasper-compiler-5.0.30` and `make sure is in your classpath before gwt`. There are other latest jasper compiler jars out-there but i'm not sore of how compatible are with `jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28`
8. https://code.google.com/archive/p/raisercostin/wikis/GwtEclipsePluginDebug.wiki
9. This maybe caused by jar conflict. Remove the `servlet-api.jar` in your `servlet/WEB-INF/` directory, `%Tomcat home%/lib` already have this lib.
10. Every time I have seen those errors the reason was jasper could not find 
    the java compiler.  Try and put `tools.jar` in your `common/lib` and see if the 
    service works then..